# How to call a method inside a viewController from didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a method inside my viewController (MainViewController.m) that accepts a parameter (Let's say it changes the background color of the viewController based on the number):

```
-(void) methodThatDoesSomething:(int)indexNumber {}
```

Inside this viewController I have a UITableView, but the delegate of this table is another class (TableDelegateClass.m). So inside this class I have didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

How do I call the "methodThatDoesSomething" from didSelectRowAtIndexPath? If I do it like this:

```
MainViewController* mainView = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
[mainView methodThatDoesSomething:indexPath.row];
```

It doesn't work. As another instance of the class is created and it doesn't after the viewController that I'm currently using.

I can easily do it if the delegate of the table is the MainViewController (just with this code inside didSelectRowAtIndexPath) :

```
[self methodThatDoesSomething:indexPath.row]
```

but I want to organize better the code and have different classes, one for the table and another for the viewController containing the table.

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution could be to define your own delegate protocol for `-(void) methodThatDoesSomething:(int)indexNumber {}` so you can set `TableDelegateClass` delegate to your viewController and then call `[delegate methodThatDoesSomething:indexPath.row];` (after checking `respondsToSelector`).
You can also pass the viewController instance when you create `TableDelegateClass` but this is a higher coupling level than delegate.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve your problem is to create a property of type MainViewController in the delegate class and assign the controller instance to it.

But maybe this problem that you are having is an indicator that the tableView delegate should indeed be the MainViewController and not another class?